# Pythonic way of initiating class with different cases of types of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, class

This is a question about "proper" code design in Python. I would like to know the opinions of you experts!

Suppose I have a class `Test()` that is initiated by either an .asc file or a numpy Array, and absolutely nothing else. I want the user of the class not to bother about how to initiate the class. For example, this is how I do it ATM:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self, asc_file=None, array=None):

    if asc_File is not None:
        self.array = read_asc_file(asc_file)  # reads and returns numpy array

    elif np_array is not None:
        self.array= np_array


    else:
        raise Exception("Need an .asc file or a numpy array as input")

    …
```

If using the code above, the user will need to type

```
Test(asc_file="filename.asc")
```

or

```
Test(array= some_numpy_array)
```

What I want is that the user can initiate the class as

```
Test("filename.asc")
```

or

```
Test(some_numpy_array)
```

and the code will handle it on its own, raising errors if it's not an asc file or a numpy Array. I'm aware that I can use the " is " methods, but I search for a nice Pythonic way of doing this that doesn't result in weird bugs.

Comment: specifying arguments to keywords (`asc_file="filename.asc"`) is already a **nice** pythonic way

Comment: Definitely, im just trying to make it as easy as possible to use this class, for users not knowing much about Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's fine to just use a single positional argument in this case, and just check the passed in argument for its type, either using `isinstance` or some duck-typing depending on the case:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, str) and os.path.exists(data):
            # Read the array from the file
            data = ...

        # In the case of Numpy arrays, many non-ndarray types (e.g.
        # lists) can be converted to Numpy arrays as well:
        try:
            data = np.asanyarray(data)
        except:
            pass

        if not isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
            raise ValueError("data argument must be a filename, an ndarray, or an object convertible to an array")

        self.data = data
```

That said, although this is a personal, subjective preference, when I have a type that can be instantiated from multiple argument types, especially if one of those is to read some data from a file, it's good practice to keep the main constructor of the class (`__init__`) *specifically* for the actual data your class is initiated with, as in just the ndarray itself.  Then add an alternative constructor as a `classmethod` for reading the data from a file, like:

```
 class Test:
     def __init__(self, data):
         # Type check data if you want...
         self.data = data

     @classmethod
     def fromfile(cls, filename):
         # Read data from a file...
         data = ...
         return cls(data)
```

Then, when instantiating a `Test` loaded from a file you would use this like:

```
>>> mytest = Test.fromfile('filename')
```

One advantage of this is if your API grows (e.g. maybe you will later want to add more arguments that are relevant only when reading from a file) you can separate the file-handling code from your lower-level constructor.  This is a good example of separation of concerns.  Also, to quote the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), this is an example of "explicit is better than implicit", as it makes it explicit when using this code that you are loading a `Test` instance from a file, and that the string couldn't possibly be anything but a filename.

Comment: Precisely what i needed ! Thanks !